# Aligning two divs horizontally and third div vertically

Tags: css

I have 3 div's, I want two divs to position horizontally and third div to be position vertically.
[image: full screen layout]

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
/*    flex-direction: column;
   */
}
.child{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 160px;
}
.child2{
  align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child child1">
1
</div>
<div class="child child2">
2
</div>
<div class="child child3">
3
</div>
</div>
```

I have to keep the same HTML structure as in snippet, to achieve the responsive layout for mobile. In mobile layout "B" comes in between "A" and "c", so Im thinking to do it using "order" property.

[image: Mobile Layout]

I have tried doing it with flex and table-row but but can't seem to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

```css
.parent{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto;

}
.child{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.child2{
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 2;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child child1">
1
</div>
<div class="child child2">
2
</div>
<div class="child child3">
3
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.grid-container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
     grid-gap: 10px;
     background-color: #2196F3;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius:10px;
}
 .grid-container > div {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
     text-align: center;
     padding: 20px 0;
     font-size: 30px;
     border-radius:10px;
}
 .item1 {
     grid-row-start: 1;
}
 .item2 {
     grid-row-start: 2;
}
 .item3 {
     grid-area: right;
     grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
```